# calling function problem (iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

From class picViewController i am calling  function imageCliked on scrollViewController
in order to fire function loadPage but it does work. Compiler error:

```
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[scrollViewController loadpage:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x17198'"
```

Anybody can help?

```
@interface scrollViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
}
- (void)loadPage:(int)page;  // loads a new picViewController
+(void) imageCliked;
@end

#import "scrollViewController.h"
#import "picViewController.h"
#import "MLUtils.h"

@implementation scrollViewController

- (void)loadPage:(int)page {
// I need to call this function from +(void) imageCliked 
}
/* this function is called by picViewController pressButton1 */

+(void) imageCliked {
NSLog(@"left");
[self loadPage:3];// does not work
}
@end





#import "picViewController.h"
#import "scrollViewController.h"

@implementation picViewController

- (void) pressButton1:(id)sender{
 [scrollViewController imageCliked];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 4):

If it is a class, please name it starting with a capital letter.

---

```
[self loadPage:3];
```

Since `self` is a class in `+imageCliked`, the `loadPage:` method must be a **class method** as well. But you're declaring `-loadPage:` as an **instance method**. The two are not exchangeable. Either

1. Make `+loadPage:` a class method (change the `-` to `+`), or
2. Create a temporary instance of `scrollViewController`, i.e. `[[[[self alloc] init] autorelease] loadPage:3];`, or
3. Make `-imageCliked` an instance method, and create an instance in `-pressButton1:`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mismatch between class methods and instance methods. Methods that start with `+` belong to the class, and ones that start with `-` belong to the instance.

The specific error you see above happens because you're trying to call an instance method (`-loadPage`) from a class method (`+imageClicked`), which doesn't work-- "self" inside of imageClicked refers to the whole class, so that's why it fails.

My guess is that you actually want both of those methods to be instance methods. Make them both prefixed with `-`.

But it sounds like you might need to review some basics in the first couple chapters of [Apple's Objective-C documentation](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH1-SW2).